# How do I add an image to the DOM after another image has loaded?

Tags: reactjs

I want to make sure images are loaded in the right order: first the primary image, then the secondary image. My plan is to inject the secondaryImage once the primary image is done.

```
class HoverImage extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { secondaryImage: null }
  }

  primaryImageLoaded () {
    //here I would like inject <img className='img-responsive' src={stripUrl(secondaryImage)} /> before primaryImage
  }

  render () {
    const primaryImage = this.props.primaryImage
    const secondaryImage = this.props.secondaryImage
    if (secondaryImage) {
      return (
        <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
          <img
            className='img-responsive'
            src={stripUrl(primaryImage)}
            onLoad={this.primaryImageLoaded.bind(this)}
            style={{
              ':hover': {
                opacity: 0
              },
              position: 'absolute',
              top: 0}}
            />
        </div>
      )
   }
}
```

other solutions that create the same effect are fine too!

Comment: nothing, I don't really know what to do or how to tackle this, In jquery I would do somthing like .prepend, but I don't know what is the react way of doing this, it's more of a design question for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HoverImage extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        firstImageLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.setState({ firstImageLoaded: true });
  }

  loadSecondImage() {
    if(this.state.firstImageLoaded) {
        return  (<img
            className='img-responsive'
            src={stripUrl(this.props.secondaryImage)}
            />);
    }
  }

  render () {
      return (
        <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
            <img
            className='img-responsive'
            src={stripUrl(this.props.primaryImage)}
            onLoad={this.setState({ firstImageLoaded: true })}
            style={{
              ':hover': {
                opacity: 0
              },
              position: 'absolute',
              top: 0}}
            />
            {this.loadSecondImage()}
        </div>
      )
}
```

When the initial mount is done, it will set a flag in the state which will trigger a re-render.

Hope that helps!

ps: this answer is in no way perfect but should get what you wanted done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class HoverImage extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { 
         secondaryImage: null,
         showSecondaryImage: false,  
      }
   }

   primaryImageLoaded () {
       this.setState({showSecondaryImage: true});
   }

   render () {
      const primaryImage = this.props.primaryImage;
      const secondaryImage = this.props.secondaryImage;
      secondaryImage ? 
        return (
           <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
               {this.state.showSecondaryImage ?
                  <img className='img-responsive' src={stripUrl(secondaryImage)} /> 
                : <div/>}
                <img
                   className='img-responsive'
                   src={stripUrl(primaryImage)}
                   onLoad={this.primaryImageLoaded.bind(this)}
                   style={{
                     ':hover': {
                         opacity: 0
                       },
                       position: 'absolute',
                       top: 0
                   }}
                 />
           </div>
        )
    : return <div/>   
    }   
}
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/d7hwzapc/

Comment: difficult to use the same code since it is using `props` n all, so just implemented the logic, that i used in this. Loading two image one after another. To show the proper effect, used the `setTimeOut funtion`.